# making alert with field sevierty and triaged in tfs 2010 with power tools

Tags: tfs, alert, tfs-power-tools, tfs-alerts

In tfs 2010 alert explorer ,i have to make alert like below

old value of severity = old value of severity and new old value of triage != (not equals to) new value of triage.

how can i do this ? as tfs alert severity/triage fields only show operator as(changes , changes from , changes to)
if they can show (=,contains) my problem will be solved!
sorry for my bad English !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this cannot be achieved through the alert explorer in TFS 2010.
You can develop it yourself with either a TFS plugin, or with a web service which you will then need to subscribe to the "WorkItemChangedEvent" via command line or the "Alert Explorer".